# Python Code to detect and mitigate TCP SYN Flood attacks in SDN and POX controller

Tags: python, sdn, pox

Does someone have a solution for detecting and mitigating TCP SYN Flood attacks in the SDN environment based on POX controller?

Answer (score 0):

As my understand, you may need to prepare third-party program for collect flow information (e.g. sFlow). and write one program for communicating with SDN Controller. SDN Controller cover all traffic on switches. It don't handle over L4 event in general case

Comment: Thanks Phil. I am looking for python code that can do the same. Any idea where i can find sample code?